# List of available ubuntu packages for ARM processors?

Tags: package-management, arm

Is there a list where I can **prefilter** architecture:arm and all ported packages appear?
Up to now I just searched by trial and error, e.g. entered the name of the package (in packages.ubuntu.com)  I am interested in, and then confirmed that the package is available for the arm-platform or not.
But that takes a lot of time for more than a few packages!

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/armhf might help a little.

Comment: Thanks,
unfortunately I get nearly always a timeout error: _Launchpad.net
Timeout error
Sorry, something just went wrong in Launchpad.
We’ve recorded what happened, and we’ll fix it as soon as possible. Apologies for the inconvenience.
Trying again in a couple of minutes might work._

Comment: Yeah, I got the same error. Sometimes, refreshing the page works, but it seems that that doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/<release>/main/binary-<architecture>/Packages.bz2` (there're different architectures for ARM - armhf, arm64, armel, etc. - and not all might be available for every release, focus on the LTS releases, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM for further infos), e.g. http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages.bz2. You'll find a list of packages which are available through `apt-get` if you add

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports <release> main
```

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The list isn't in handy format, but decompressing and opening it with a text editor and using its search function will help.