# Trouble with apt-get update and default repositories

Tags: apt, updates

I am having problems when I run: sudo apt-get update

I get a few 404 not found errors, as seen in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caHtJ.png) and the following text:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm not sure what is causing this, I tried changing the update server, and I tried using a VPN to ensure my IP hasn't been blacklisted. Neither of those worked. Anyone know how to fix this? I am using Ubuntu 18.04

I tried [restoring the default repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories), but that didn't fix the problem. Below is my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

If I comment out everything in /etc/apt/sources.list, then I do not get any errors, but it does not check for Ubuntu updates as seen below:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Reading package lists... Done
```

I also tried leaving 1 line uncommented at a time, to see if any of them would work, but they all caused errors.

I do not believe IPv6 is the issue, as I was able to run ping6:

```
$ ping6 2001:67c:1560:8001::14
PING 2001:67c:1560:8001::14(2001:67c:1560:8001::14) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1560:8001::14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=90.4 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1560:8001::14: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=89.8 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1560:8001::14: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=86.7 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1560:8001::14: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=86.2 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1560:8001::14: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=95.2 ms
```

Running `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` returned:

```
i386
armhf
```

I tried using ports.ubuntu.com by adding `deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, as shown in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431375/list-of-available-ubuntu-packages-for-arm-processors), but I still got the same errors.

I am ultimately trying to install a Nextcloud server, but I'm unable to install MariaDB for it, and I think this update issue the cause.

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, they are much harder to read & cannot be copy/pasted from to work out the issue.  You have access to the actual text; you can copy/paste & look up your issues.

Comment: I think you may be right N0rbert, I'll look into that solution.

Comment: What do you get after `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`?

Comment: I've not heard of arm-hf packages (presumably some subset of ARM), but look at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/, those files aren't found because they don't exist on the server. I looked at the gb.archive.ubuntu.com mirror and they're not in there either. It seems you've either got your architecture or server addresses wrong. Looks like you need ports.ubuntu.com, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/431375/list-of-available-ubuntu-packages-for-arm-processors.

Comment: Why do you have `armhf` as an architecture? Is there something that you installed that enabled it? You'll need to either remove that architecture, add an `arch` filter to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` lines, or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure why I even have it Chai T. Rex, but I removed it and that solved the problem. Everything else still works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: I ran `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf` and that solved the problem. When I ran `sudo apt-get update` it no longer tried to get `binary-armhf` packages. I found this solution in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/705903/976049).